# How can I build a multidimensional array in JSON and pass it to ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

I'm having some troubles with a multidimensional array. My php code is as follows:

```
$result = array();
$count = 0;

    foreach($matches_lines as $lines){

        $match_user = $lines["signup_username"];
        $match_birth = $lines["signup_birth"];
        $match_city = $lines["signup_city"];
        $match_gender = $lines["signup_gender"];
        $match_os = $lines["signup_os"];
        $match_persontype = $lines["signup_persontype"];

        if("some check on the variables"){

            $result[$count] = array('username' => "$match_user", 'birth'=> "$match_birth", 'city' => "$match_city", 'gender' => "$match_gender", 'os' => "$match_os", 'persontype' => "$match_persontype");
            $count = $count + 1;
            }
        }       
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

while my ajax request looks like this:

```
$("#select_age").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "get_matches.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
            min_search: $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ),
            max_search: $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )
            },
            success: function(data){
                var myvar = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                window.alert(myvar)
            }
        });
});
```

A var_dump($result) should look like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "giulia"
    ["birth"]=>
    string(10) "05/10/1990"
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "Torino"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "F"
    ["os"]=>
    string(7) "Windows"
    ["persontype"]=>
    string(4) "ENFP"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(7) "taiga27"
    ["birth"]=>
    string(10) "07/27/1998"
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "Torino"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "F"
    ["os"]=>
    string(7) "Windows"
    ["persontype"]=>
    string(4) "ISTP"
  }
}
```

When I get to the  var myvar = jQuery.parseJSON(data); I get an error "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2"

What am I getting wrong? How do I initialize a correct JSON multidimensional array inside a foreach? And how do I to retrieve the data once in the ajax success function?

Comment: var_dump is not producing an JSON output. use json_encode instead

Comment: Also, building this array can be automatic in SQL if the data is coming from a DB.

Comment: Try to use your browsers inspector/developer tools to see the content of the ajax (xhr) request. There might be other output before the json data that makes it impossible to use parseJSON()

Comment: AbraCadaver  yeah I edited my post because I forgot I have to check a condition o some of the variables, that's why I didn't use the automatic conversion from SQL to JSON

Comment: Use https://jsonlint.com/ to check where is the error in your JSON.

Comment: Marco It says   Error: Parse error on line 1:
array(2) { [0] => 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: The `dataType: "json",` part of your code must be out of `data: {}`, block.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

You do not need to increment `$count` in order to append to an array. Simply exclude the index (see below).

You do not need to place your variables inside double quotes. Simply pass the variable without any quotation marks at all.

Your example code has some extra closing brackets, maybe you have other code before/after what you shared, but if not, you certainly don't need so many brackets.

You should not use `var_dump()` to return the data, simply `echo()` the JSON-encoded results string (as you have in your example).

```
$result = array();

foreach($matches_lines as $lines){

        $match_user = $lines["signup_username"];
        $match_birth = $lines["signup_birth"];
        $match_city = $lines["signup_city"];
        $match_gender = $lines["signup_gender"];
        $match_os = $lines["signup_os"];
        $match_persontype = $lines["signup_persontype"];

        if( 1 == 1 ){ // replace with "some check on the variables"
            $result[] = array('username' => $match_user, 'birth'=> $match_birth, 'city' => $match_city, 'gender' => $match_gender, 'os' => $match_os, 'persontype' => $match_persontype);
        }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Doing that I now get (lookign at the console) this as an echo  
0: {username: "giulia", birth: "05/10/1990", city: "Torino", gender: "F", os: "Windows",…}

1: {username: "taiga27", birth: "07/27/1998", city: "Torino", gender: "F", os: "Windows",…}